# Enable multiple sounds on phonegap build?

Tags: cordova, media

I want to do the following:

```
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/pull/33
```

but in phonegap build, which i have only one file to config and it's the config.xml,

There i put:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media"/>
```

But i have background music,  and little sounds here and there, i want all sounds to not interfere with one another, right now when a sound is played, and ends, the bg music also ends for some reason.

Anyone knows a solution for this for phonegap-build?

Update:

Im now trying this one:

```
https://github.com/SidneyS/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio/blob/239e9f1/README.md
```

but it seems not to work,  asset not exist that tells me, everytime, anyone knows something about this one? is it working at all?

Comment: Bare in mind that playing multiple audio files is not possible on iOS: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video.pdf#page21 You would need to creat an audio sprite, and play different sections of that sprite, to simulate multiple files. To play them at the same time, create multiple media instances, using the same source audio file.

Comment: can you show the code where you start playing the sounds?